# Unable to query BigQuery Metadata tables using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery

I am using BigQuery Spark 0.22.0 connector with Spark 2.3.0.

A table gets created daily under my bigquery dataset daily and I need to query the metadata tables to see if the table has been created or not so I can query it. I can also do that with exception handling but I thought this would be easier because I need to check if the tables are present for a date range.

I am able to connect to BigQuery and query normal tables under the schema/dataset but while querying the metadata tables/views like `__TABLES__` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`, the code fails.

While trying to query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`

```scala
spark.read
     .format("bigquery")
     .option("credentials", <key>)
     .option("parentProject", <projectId>)
     .option("viewsEnabled", "true")
     .option("materializationDataset", <datasetId>)
     .load("<projectId>.<datasetId>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES")
```

I get the following error:

> ```scala
> Project IDs must contain 6-63 lowercase letters, digits, or dashes. Some project IDs also include domain name separated by a colon. IDs must start with a letter and may not end with a dash.
> ```

And while trying to query `__TABLES__`

```scala
spark.read
     .format("bigquery")
     .option("credentials", <key>)
     .option("parentProject", <projectId>)
     .option("viewsEnabled", "true")
     .option("materializationDataset", <datasetId>)
     .load("<projectId>.<datasetId>.__TABLES__")

//res13: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [project_id: string, dataset_id: string ... 6 more fields]
```

I get hit with the following error:

> ```scala
> com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.gax.rpc.InternalException: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: request failed: internal error
> ```

I have also tried setting this properties in the Spark Conf but it didn't work:

```scala
spark.conf.set("viewsEnabled","true")
spark.conf.set("materializationDataset","<dataset>")
```

Any idea how these views can be queried in Spark? Or any alternatives as to how it can be checked if a table exists in BigQuery or not (without the `try-catch` stuff)?

Comment: Have you pasted it exectly like this: `.load("<projectId>.<datasetId>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES"`? at least it seems like this looking at  this error....

Comment: @vitooh Yes, there are no typos.

Comment: It seems that you used boilerplate code without pasting your procjet ID. Isn't it?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor Nope. Couldn't get it to work so moved on to the try-catch stuff eventually.